# ie9 scroll bar and etched border always showing on object

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, scrollbar, border

I've got some simple html and css (see below) that shows a flex app inside a Div tag. In most browsers (ie8, chrome, FF), the object doesn't have a border or a vertical scrollbar. In ie9, both a scrollbar and a 3D etched border are shown. I'd like to remove those, I tried various border styles but nothing seem to help. Does anyone have a solution for this? Is this a known problem for ie9 only?

I'm kind of new to Html, CSS, javascript, etc. and I have to say, IE browsers are a pain!

```
  #mapLocation
  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 131px;
    left:0;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: none;
  }

  #mapObject{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: none; 
  }
</style>


<div id="mapLocation" >
    <object id="mapObject" type="text/html" data="otherFile.html"></object>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help,

Ggilmann

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604589/php-versions-ie9-css-clashes-of-the-select-element#comment16990153_12604589). It may be a compatibility mode that is switched on in your IE9 browser. Try to uncheck it.