# PHP versions/IE9 CSS clashes of the select element

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer

I build a web application on PHP 5.4.3 and I have a `<select><option>` element with a CSS property `border:none`, and indeed when I run the application on IE9 on localhost it's fine. However, the actual environment where the application should be stored in production, has the PHP 5.1.6 installed, and when running the application on IE9 on the production environment the border looks like a dark 3D border in windows application or a textbox boundaries. I tested with different CSS properties and there's no impact - looks like IE9 with PHP 5.1.6 completely ignores border CSS settings (which again, on my localhost it was tested fine).

It does not happening with Chrome, FF, Safari or Opera - just with IE.

Upgrading the production PHP is unfortunately not an option.

Screenshots:

IE9 with PHP 5.4.3 (local host) - No border.

[image]

IE9 with PHP 5.1.6 (production) - Black 3D border.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you compared the HTML itself to see what is different?

Comment: How does your CSS looks like exactly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP has nothing to do with how the browser renders the select box. Could it be that you are viewing it in compatibility mode? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/compatibility-view

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with PHP... PHP is server-side, meaning your installation does not affect the styles and look. Give us a link, or the html and css so we can look at it. My guess is, you need to use outline:none; on an element

Comment: what do you mean? the HTML is the same on local and production

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with how browsers render CSS, there will be something else causing this. Post your HTML/CSS

Comment: I honestly don't have any clue to what's happening exactly, but I thing you should have a look to headers both on local & distant envs. The issue is probably not from PHP itself, but maybe from a weird header sent by the HTTP server.

Comment: @MrMisterMan you are 100% right - it's the compatibility mode! Thanks!

Comment: @EricPeters Damn! Should have put that as an answer.... :)

Answer (score 1):

IE9 can remember the rendering mode for certain domains. If you manually switched *browser mode* in IE developer tools it will remember your choice. Please make sure `Browser Mode` and `Document Mode` are set to value marked as `Page Default`.

Answer (score -1):

It won't be PHP that determines how CSS and HTML renders. That literally won't have anything to do with it.

Comment: I am trying to stop him wasting his time. The version of PHP will make no difference to how the CSS and HTML render.